# C++ SFINAE operator/function result type check

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I am writing a template-based class for Polynomials. (Evaluation, some operations between Polynomials, differentiation, ...), like this:
`template <typename _ty> class Polynomial{...`

For the `to_string` function (and the `std::ostream`-left-shift-override), I had to check, if `_ty` supports the `<`-operator (i.e. yes for real numbers, no for complex numbers), so that the string could be formatted nicely. For this I use this code:

```c++
#include <type_traits>

template <class _op, class... _ty, typename = decltype(std::declval<_op>()(std::declval<_ty>()...))>
std::true_type impl_test(const _op&, const _ty&...) { return std::true_type(); }
std::false_type impl_test(...) { return std::false_type(); }
template <class> struct supports;
template <class _op, class... _ty> struct supports<_op(_ty...)> : decltype(impl_test(std::declval<_op>(), std::declval<_ty>()...)){};

#define is_ineq_supported(type) supports<std::less<>(type, type)>()
```

In short, `is_ineq_supported(type)` returns an `std::true_type` if there is a valid overload for the `<`-operator, and a `false_type` if not. The corresponding functions can then be called with a `true_type` or `false_type` as the distinguishing argument, like this:

```c++
template <typename _ty> void do_stuff(_ty arg, const std::true_type&) {
    // do stuff with the '<'-operator
}

template <typename _ty> void do_stuff(_ty arg, const std::false_type&) {
    // do stuff without the '<'-operator
}

template <typename _ty> void do_stuff(_ty arg) {
    do_stuff(arg, is_ineq_supported(_ty));
}
```

I also have a Vector class, that overloads the binary `*`-operator with the dot product, so it returns a `double`. But for a polynomial, it only makes sense, to have coefficients and arguments, which return the same type when multiplied with one another.

**My problem is the following:** I'd like to have a way of checking, if the given operation returns a specified type. (maybe a similar macro?) I  think, the simplest would be something that returns a `true_type` if the result type matches the argument type and a `false_type` otherwise. Of course, more general solutions are even better.

In case, the IDE and Compiler matter: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with default settings.

Comment: "*(...) if the given operation returns a specified type*", maybe it would be better to check if the returned type is implicitly convertible to something ?

Comment: `std::is_same` (or `std::is_convertible`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic, cross-platform solution using [`fit::is_callable`](http://fit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/is_callable/index.html), which will be eventually added to Boost. Also keep your eye out for [`std::is_callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable) in C++17.

No macros necessary:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fit/is_callable.hpp>

// std::less doesn't SFINAE, so we make our own test
struct less_test {
    template<typename L, typename R>
    auto operator()(L l, R r) -> decltype(l < r);
};

template<typename T>
using is_less_than_comparable = fit::is_callable<less_test, T, T>;

// operator< version (replace with your implementation)
template <typename T> constexpr auto
do_stuff(T arg, const std::true_type&) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, 0>{};
}

// other version (replace with your implementation)
template <typename T> constexpr auto
do_stuff(T arg, const std::false_type&) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, 1>{};
}

template <typename T> constexpr auto
do_stuff(T arg) {
    return do_stuff(arg, is_less_than_comparable<T>{});
}

struct foo {};

int main() {

    //is not less-than comparable
    static_assert(do_stuff(foo{}) == 1, "");

    //is less-than comparable
    static_assert(do_stuff(0) == 0, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reconsider your member method detectors and use the most *C++11-ish* `void_t` based solution.

That said, if I had to update your solution, probably the following code is a viable approach:

```
template <class _op, class _ret, class... _ty>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<_op>()(std::declval<_ty>()...)), _ret>::value, std::true_type>::type
impl_test(const _op&, const _ty&...) {
    return std::true_type();
}
```

This will work as it follows:

```
struct S { int operator()() { return 42; } };

int main() {
    assert((impl_test<S, int>(S{})));
    // this will give you an error at compile time
    // assert((impl_test<S, double>(S{})));
}
```